# Picard groups of blow-up

Tags: complex-geometry, blowup

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold and $Y$ a complex sub manifold of codimension $\ge 2$. If $\pi : X_{Y} \mapsto X$ is the blow-up of $X$ along $Y$, do you have any references for this result :

-$Pic(X_{Y}) = \pi^{*}Pic(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}$? (whithout using "pure" algebraic geometry arguments but only complex geometry).

Here $Pic(X) = H^{1}(X, \mathcal{O}_{X}^{*})$ are all the classes of isomorphism of holomorphic line bundles over $X$.

I thank you in advance and wish you a good day.

Comment: You don’t mean $\otimes$ :)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much :).

Comment: The answer can be found here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349970/picard-group-of-blowup-of-smooth-variety/4352491#4352491

Comment: It uses algebraic geometry arguments but the parallel is clear for me. Thank you very much.